# Mysql Change timezone for hosting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a server in `godaddy`.
In `php` i use that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Beirut');
```

I try to change `mysql` timezone.

I try many thing but i can't have a solution.

This is what i did:

```
SET time_zone ="Asia/Beirut";
```

also i tried this:

```
SET time_zone ="LB";
```

But i receive this message:

**Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Beirut'**

this message also appear for **LB**

How Can i change my current mysql time zone to my own Lebanon Beirut ???

```
DATE(phonecall.db_nextdate)=CURDATE()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: I recommend you leave mysql and the server with UTC timezone, and when it presents the values ​​performs the conversion to the local date

Comment: @rikardo_paiva how can i change in my query to my local date i use curdate() to do that can you please check above

Answer (score 0):

---

change it in using htaccess

```
SetEnv TZ Asia/Beirut
```

---

OR

```
php_value date.timezone 'Asia/Beirut'
```